# For further reading or read

Tags: grammar

Can "read" replace "reading" in the following sentence? Also, is it correct to say "save this link for future reading/read? Thank you!

"[For further reading, see Vinson & Elkins, I.R.S. Affirms and Expands the Scope of Qualifying Income for M.L.P.'s.](https://archive.nytimes.com/dealbook.nytimes.com/2013/06/18/how-the-i-r-s-encourages-oil-and-gas-spinoffs/#:%7E:text=For%20further%20reading%2C%20see%20Vinson%20%26%20Elkins%2C%20I.R.S.%20Affirms%20and%20Expands%20the%20Scope%20of%20Qualifying%20Income%20for%20M.L.P.%27s.%20)"

Comment: No and *"save ... for future use"*.

Comment: No, and frankly, this is very googleable.

Comment: Thank you all!
I have googled "save for future read " https://www.google.com/search?q=save+for+future+read&oq=save+for+future+read&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l4j33i22i29i30l4.9765j0j4&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8 and "save for future reading" https://www.google.com/search?q=save+for+future+reading&oq=save+for+future+reading&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l4j33i22i29i30.2363j0j7&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8, but nothing came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Reading" takes the place of a noun in this sentence and means "reading material," so no, you can not replace it with the verb "read" (which can't take the place of a noun).
You can say "save this link for future reading," but not "for future read," for the same reason.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I am confused about something: According to this  "link" https://www.thefreedictionary.com/read#:~:text=ing%20(%CB%88ri%20d%C9%AA%C5%8B)-,n.,understand%20things%20written%20in%20it., "read" can be used as a noun. Also, I have heard people say "this is a good read", using "read" as a noun. Thank you!