# Can "read" be used as a noun?

Tags: grammar

I understand that "read" is a verb and that "[reading](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/327035/for-further-reading-or-read?noredirect=1#comment616863_327035)" is a noun, so it's wrong to say "save this article for future read". However, how come this [link](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/read#:%7E:text=ing%20(%CB%88ri%20d%C9%AA%C5%8B)-,n.,understand%20things%20written%20in%20it.) says "read" can also be used as a noun? Also, I have heard people say "this is a good read", using "read" as a noun. I am confused. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: We can say informally that a book is 'a good read', so 'save it for **a** future read' might be acceptable but very casual and informal.

Comment: Have you checked any dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English is very flexible about using common words like "read". This is partly due to the fact that English has very simple conjugation for nouns and verbs, and so a word can be made into a noun simply by using it as a noun.

In this case "read" as a noun can either mean (by metonymy) a book, or an instance or period of reading::

> The fifth book in the Harry Potter series is a long read.

> Katie went upstairs for a read before bed.

Dictionaries also mention some other niche meanings, eg in computing.

> This disc can achieve 1000 reads a second.

The flexibility of English to use words as both nouns and verbs means that it is possible to "read a book" and to "book a read" (ie arrange a time for a period of reading).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by '*words like "read"*'? Do you mean verbs in general?

Comment: Common words like read.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it that way. It means "experience or process of reading".

> *Gilead* is a good read.

> The article's a long read, but it's very worthwhile.